# Fast Fourier Transform for radial forces in Python

Tags: python, numpy, fft

First of all I want to say that I am very new in this and some help it would be welcome. I want to calculate fft for radial forces and something I'm missing. Until now I have something like this:

```
t=np.arange(145)
sp=np.fft.fft(radial_force)
freq=np.fft.fftfreq(t.shape[-1])
pl.plot(freq, radial_force.real, freq,radial_force.imag)
pl.show()
```

I get really big values and I don't know why. Any hint would be helpful.
Thank you in advance !

Comment: I'm not familiar with radial force , but if you give more information about your input me or maybe someone else could help you with the fft part !

Comment: You usually need to normalize the spectrum that comes out of fft. But as @mjsameri noted, your question is missing a [MCVE] and is pretty vague. Also please read [ask].